# Vaadin -> Vaadin GWT Polymer elements integration

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea, vaadin

I'm building a web app using Vaadin 7 and after the recent blog post regarding the Polymer elements, I would like to integrate these into my build as well.  However, from the tutorial/example on github versus my pom created by the archetype, I'm not entirely certain how to do this.

The archetype build included org.codehuas.plexus and i see the GWT build uses mojo.  Is there a difference or just a newer version of the plugin?  (I'm very new to web app development and normally rely on Gradle not Maven.)  For example, would this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
            <jsInteropMode>JS</jsInteropMode>
            ...
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Replace the plexus plugin or be in addition to it?  I'm not sure how to set up the project when having a pre-existing vaadin project with all its long list of plugins and dependencies in the pom to using vaading GWT.  So if anyone has an example and could explain what is actually required between the different poms, that would great!

I suppose I should also ask how to use GWT elements from the Vaadin GWT within a Vaadin 7 project.  So if I was to add a Vaadin Button to a Component, it would be done the simple Java way of:

```
Button button = new Button();
```

Is this similar to what can be done with the GWT-Vaadin?  E.g.

```
PaperButton button = new PaperButton();
```

Or does it require using the xml files to create layouts similar to the Android  design patterns?

Does EntryPoint replace a Component or a View in Vaadin?  Will they work together if I can create a CustomComponent with GWT elements/widgets and use Navigator to load the container layout?  (Confused about the EntryPoint usage)

I'm using IntelliJ, btw, as Eclipse is by far my least preferred IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://vaadin.com/addon/elements-add-on for nice integration and last few slides of http://www.slideshare.net/joonaslehtinen/web-components-for-java-developers for a simple example.

Comment: That has given me some insight into how to create the components, cheers!  Using that elements add-on library will allow me to workaround the gwt-maven-plugin issue in my pom?